# Holomorphic functions series involving exponentials

Tags: complex-analysis

We have a strictly increasing sequence of reals $(\lambda _n)_{n \in\mathbb{N}}$ which tends to $+\infty$. We have another sequence of non-negative reals $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. We are interested in the series $$f(z)=\sum_{n\geqslant0} a_n \exp(-\lambda_nz), z \in \mathbb{C}.$$ We know that the series converges in $\{\Re(z)>\rho\}$ for some $\rho\in\mathbb{R}$. The function that it defines is holomorphic and can be holomorphicly extended to some neighborhood of $\rho$. There exists $\epsilon>0$ such that we can extend $f$ to a holomorphic function in the disc $D(1+\rho,1+\epsilon)$. The aim would be to find the coefficients of a Taylor series of $f$ at $1+\rho$. We can differentiate term by term (Weierstrass theorem?) so we should get $$f^{(k)}(1+\rho)=\sum_{n\geqslant0}a_n(-\lambda_n)^k\exp(-\lambda_n(1+\rho)).$$ However, I would like to get a closed form of this expression without the sigma sign in terms of $f$ maybe. After this, we have to show that the series $f(\rho-\epsilon')$ converges when $\epsilon'<\epsilon$.

Comment: Do you know anything more about the $a_n$? I don't think you can conclude the series converges in some half-plane if not; take for example $a_n=e^{n!}$ and $\lambda_n=n$. Then the series is always divergent.

Comment: Let's just say that $a_n$ and $\lambda_n$ are such that the series converges in $\{\Re(z)>\rho\}$ for some finite $\rho\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it's a rather easy exercise, I have just figured it out.

The given expression of $f^{(k)}(1+\rho)$ need not to be simplified. We note $\overline{f}$ the holomorphic extension of $f$ in $D(1+\rho, 1+\epsilon)$. By the principle of analytic continuation, in this disc $\overline{f}(z)$ is the sum of its Taylor series at $z=1+\rho$ where it coincides with $f$. While $\epsilon'<\epsilon$, we have $\rho-\epsilon'\in D(1+\rho, 1+\epsilon)$, hence $$\overline{f}(\rho-\epsilon')=\sum_{k\geqslant0}(\rho-\epsilon'-1-\rho)^k\left(\sum_{n\geqslant0}a_n\frac{(-\lambda_n)^k}{k!}\exp(-\lambda_n(1+\rho))\right).$$
Now, sum is convergent and all the terms are non-negative, hence we can inverse the two sums and use the definition of the exponential function:
$$\overline{f}(\rho-\epsilon')=\sum_{n\geqslant0}a_n\exp(-\lambda_n(1+\rho))\left(\sum_{k\geqslant0}\frac{\lambda_n^k(1+\epsilon')^k}{k!}\right)=\sum_{n\geqslant0}a_n\exp(-\lambda_n(\rho-\epsilon'))=f(\rho-\epsilon').$$ Done.